# How to continue application after waiting a thread return results

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, qthread

I want to continue application after waiting a thread complete in PyQt5. In this code, `self.capture_handle.relabeling_thread()` gets current image in widget and after display it into new widget. I use `time.sleep(0.3)` to wait thread getting image. I think this way is so bad. So how can I do without the need to use `time.sleep(0.3)`?

```
def relabeling(self):
    self.capture_handle.relabeling_thread() # get image
    time.sleep(0.3) # wait thread complete
    self.labeling.mainWidget.setCurrentImage(path_save_cvImage) # displai image into new widget
    
    self.labeling.setBtnEnable(1)
    self.labeling.reset_json()
    self.labeling.show()
```

`relabeling_thread()` function to emit a signal requiring a thread of camera to get a image (the same capture image in camera)

```
def relabeling_thread(self):
    signal = 1
    self.proxy_relabeling_signal.my_signal_relabeling.emit(signal)
```

here thread of camera:

```
def stream_predict_thread(self):
    try:
      
        if threashold > 0 and threashold < 1 and self.model_yolo != 0:
            self.thread[2] = PREDICT_IMAGE(index=2, cv_image_path = path_save_edited_Image, model=self.model_yolo, threashold = threashold)
            self.thread[2].start()
           
            self.proxy_relabeling_signal.my_signal_relabeling.connect(self.thread[2].proxy_relabeling.my_signal_relabeling.emit)
```

Comment: How does the relabeling_thread() works ? Does it create a thread ? If yes, you should use the join() function on the thread to wait for it to complete.

Comment: relabeling_thread() emits a signal to a thread_camera() to get image. How can I join thread?

Comment: Can you add this function to your post ?

Comment: I have already update my post. Hope you to help me!

Comment: Please provide a valid [mre].